# Issue with vscode syntax highlighting for svelte files

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

Vscode seems to be weirdly highlighting some of my html elements in .svelte files. this is so distracting its borderline unusable. This seems to be most evident in the `button` element. Has anyone encountered this before?

I currently have 3 svelte extensions installed. I've tried disabling, uninstalling, etc and none seem to fix it. I've tried updating vscode, no fix either.

```
Name: Svelte Intellisense
Id: ardenivanov.svelte-intellisense
Description: Provides intellisense for data, events, slots etc. in components.
Version: 0.7.1
Publisher: ardenivanov
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ardenivanov.svelte-intellisense


Name: Svelte for VS Code
Id: svelte.svelte-vscode
Description: Svelte language support for VS Code
Version: 106.0.0
Publisher: Svelte
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode

Name: Svelte 3 Snippets
Id: fivethree.vscode-svelte-snippets
Description: Svelte 3 Snippets for VS Code
Version: 0.5.0
Publisher: fivethree
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fivethree.vscode-svelte-snippets
```

(yes, I know there are some issues with the variable access (button vs b) but just pay attention to the word `button` being highlighted in two colors.

[image]

Comment: You should not need `Svelte Intellisense` if you have `Svelte for VS Code`, if anything they should cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable source maps, usually done in a `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "sourceMap": true,
    }
}
```

For Svelte some settings should be set, there is a base config that can be extended: [`@tsconfig/svelte`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/svelte)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve it for me. I've added the options in tsconfig and its set to extend the svelte/tsconfig.. no luck.

Comment: Did you restart VS Code/the language server?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately still having issues with this. Maybe something is corrupt - I'll try recreating the project.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with another extension you've installed. VS Code has a neat [bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect#_welcome-extension-bisect) feature that can be useful here.

If that doesn't reveal anything, check your settings/theme-settings for anything related to appearance/color. You use the `@modified` flag to only display the modified settings in the settings window to search faster.